# Parsing JSON data without quotes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to parse JSON with jQuery I get from a remote server through AJAX.  The JSON data is like: `{identifier:"ID", label:"LABEL"}` but unable to.  Apparently, the field identifier and label has no double quotes. It works when tested on my local test site with double quotes.

Can it be made to work without quotes with jQuery? I have searched around and have found no solutions.

Any input is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you not get the JSON correctly formatted?

Comment: I'm guessing you have no control over the remote server? Passing bad JSON is something they should be fixing, even if you don't have control on that server (email them?). Can you post an example of the bad JSON? Maybe there's a regex fix or something quick and dirty if you absolutely can't change the API.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use eval

Comment: Do you have to do it on the client side? Jackson can read such malformed JSON for you, but it's Java and server side.

Comment: You might have figured it out from the previous comments, but developers like being obtuse, so here it is clearly: this is not valid JSON. Creating a hack to read invalid JSON is not a good approach. You should be getting valid JSON to begin with.

Comment: @GregPettit Fair enough, but you can't always convince someone to change their API right away, or at all (someone else using the API may depend on this malformed output). OP may be aware of this, and have no choice. good approach != only approach, unfortunately.

Comment: @brandwaffle You are right, I have no control over the data unfortunately.

Thanks for all inputs. Now confirmed it is bad data. I think I need a workaround to fix the bad data.

Comment: @brandwaffle I agree; just wanted to be extra-clear that it's not "differently-formatted JSON" but "incorrect JSON". Whether he needs to compensate for that or not is another story. ;-) There's rarely a case that you "cannot" affect the data source (even a 3rd-party API can be patched if you file a bug report, but more often it's just that the front-end have little direct contact with back-end and don't want to rock the boat). Me, I would fight tooth and nail before resigning myself to using a broken API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. JSON specification says this:

```
A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string. A string is very much like a C or Java string.
```

Meaning string as the label you mention.

Source: http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, it's not valid JSON, blahblahblah... like everyone cares if it's valid or not.

At least I don't care, I just want to parse it, so I wrote jsonlite.

with [Jsonlite](http://deerchao.net/projects/jsonlite/index.htm), you can do this:

```
var s = '{name: jsonlite, birthday: {year: 2013, month: 7, day: 7}, isGreat: true}';
var obj = jsonlite.parse(s);
```

Which produces exactly the same result as the code below:

```
var s = '{"name": "jsonlite", "birthday": {"year": 2013, "month": 7, "day": 7}, "isGreat": true}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(s);
```

Comment: nice one :) +10 for 'blahblahblah' :D

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression the invalid JSON can be made valid JSON.
In example below the sFixed will be valid JSON, which can be parsed: .

```
let s = '{identifier:"ID", label:"LABEL"}',
    sFixed = s.replace(/(['"])?([a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*[a-zA-Z0-9_])(['"])?:/g, '"$2": '), //'{"identifier":"ID", "label":"LABEL"}'
    obj = JSON.parse(sFixed);
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)