# how to get arrays inside objects , remove double quotes and make it as an object to put inside json syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i make jsonstring like this:

```
  { "dataTarget":["[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]",
                  "[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]"],
     "dataRealisasi" :["[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]",
                      "[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]"]

     }
```

i retrieve it thru jquery ajax and parse it

```
 var dataChart =  JSON.parse(msg.d);                   
 var dataTarget = dataChart['dataTarget']
 var dataRealisasi = dataChart['dataRealisasi']
```

i console log dataTarget  , this is the result :

```
["[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]", "[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]"]
```

what i need is a variable that is like this

```
[
[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00],
[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]
]
```

which i can pass it as a variable into this

```
  $('#container3').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monitoring Proyek'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Proyek'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Target (%)'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} %'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    series:  [{
        "name": "Proyeksi Target",          
        "data":  dataTarget // this is the variable


    }, {
        name: 'Realisasi',
        data: 
           dataRealisasi // this is the variable

    }]

     });
```

update:
the problem is when i create json string without the double quote then JSON.parse it returns error... 
i already change the server side function and return object :

```
[["Date.UTC(2016,3,01)",10.00], ["Date.UTC(2016,1,01)",5.00]]
```

, now i need to remove the the double quotes and change it too :

```
[[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00], [Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]]
```

need help here...

Comment: Fix the server instead of client _monkey-patching_

Comment: how to do that? the problem is if i dont use double quotes then it will get error when JSON.parse it....  i already change the server side function and return  :       [["Date.UTC(2016,3,01)",10.00], ["Date.UTC(2016,1,01)",5.00]]   , now i need to remove the the double quotes and change it too : [[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00], [Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]]

Comment: remove the quotes in the json file?

Comment: sent valid date strings or timestamps

Comment: @wrleskovec how can you do that? Would be invalid json.

Comment: @wrleskovec i tried to change the function to generate json which no double quotes... but if i JSON.parse it , it returns error

Comment: your question may be already asked by others before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618027/parsing-json-data-without-quotes-with-jquery

Comment: If you can remove quotes around dates on server, then you could just change `x=JSON.parse(y)` to `x=eval(y)`, which people here will say is bad, but in my opinion is quite ok in your case. Or you could extract needed "date strings" in js and eval only them.

Comment: @SergeSeredenko  i try it... the raw data is : { "dataTarget":[[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00],[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]], "dataRealisasi" :[[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00],[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]]}                                                                 then i retrieve it thru jquery ajax, i use eval(msg.d) then  the result is :   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @user1851384 sorry, js issues. `eval('(' + msg.d+ ')')` will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't know about the leading 0 so I would clean that off

```
 // the data 
var data = [
    "[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]", 
    "[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]"
];

var clean = function(n){  // remove leadin zero as we want the numbers.
  return Number(n.replace(/^0+?/, ""));
}

// removes unneeded characters "Date.UTC(", ")","[","]"
// split to an array of strings. Clean of leading zeros ? and convert to numbers
var convert = function(str){
  var n = str.replace(/Date.UTC\(|\)|\[|\]/g, "").split(",").map(clean);
  return [Date.UTC(n[0], n[1], n[2]), n[3]]; // get date and return the array item as an array
}
// Start the ball rolling.
try{
    data = data.map(convert);
}catch(e){
    console.log("You are having a bad day!");
}
// data === [[1459468800000, 10], [1454284800000, 5]];
```

Comment: thanks.. but i got error : TypeError: data.map is not a function. previously i have changed the string to var data = [
    ["Date.UTC(2016,3,01)",10.00], 
    ["Date.UTC(2016,1,01)",5.00]
];   is it the cause?

Comment: For `data.map` to throw that error data must not be an array or you are using a very old browser. That said my answer will not work with the changes you have made to the input data.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform json like this (do not use eval):

```
[
    "[Date.UTC(2016,3,01),10.00]", 
    "[Date.UTC(2016,1,01),5.00]"
].map(function(v){
    return new Function('return ' + v)();
});
```

but strongly recommend you just use the timestamp, because this transform is have a bit more cost then as usual

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618027/parsing-json-data-without-quotes-with-jquery don't work if string key has a ','.It only can work in few simple situation